# Kaspersky false positive in onepage checkout, Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.0.1

Well, I tested my checkout on a Windows machine that has Kaspersky antivírus active, and got a redirect to the shopping cart on order completion.

http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t304311.html also has this problem, a false positive.

Anyone fancy why in the source it triggers that event in Kaspersky ?

> Denied:
>   http://magento9.mydomain.com.br/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/
>   (análise usando o banco de dados de URLs de phishing)
>   http://magento9.mydomain.com.br/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/
>   20/10/2014 17:03:02

I am looking on how to submit that to kaspersky, just posted to raise awareness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Kaspersky and the issue was resolved. It was not a problem with Magento, just the URL of my domain was blacklisted.

Comment: Hi, i just want to know, how much time does they take to answer you?

Comment: newvirus@kaspersky.com Send e-mail with your report to this address, they reply quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the link via VirusDesk and scan it. Assuming the scan says the link is blacklisted, you're supposed to click a button saying the scan is wrong.

Unfortunately for me, the online scan says the link is safe. I don't want to click the button to say that I disagree with this. My Kaspersky is up to date.

I had to use the livechat and was told to contact customerservicesolution at kaspersky.com