# Checkout page forbidden by antivirus

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have a magento 1.9.1.2 installation and from some browsers, right after clicking  shipping rate button in one page checkout, the page redirects to cart page. When I checked console it showed 499:Request has been forbidden by antivirus error.

[image]

How can I fix this error

Answer (score 2):

that's correct it might be kaspersky antivirus.please refer

1) [499 Request forbidden by antivirus during checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56361/499-request-forbidden-by-antivirus-during-checkout)

2) [Dangerous URL blocked on Magento checkout by Kapersky Internet Security Scanner](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99051/dangerous-url-blocked-on-magento-checkout-by-kapersky-internet-security-scanner)
 3) [Kaspersky false positive in onepage checkout, Magento 1.9 CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/kaspersky-false-positive-in-onepage-checkout-magento-1-9-ce)

hope this will help you.